# Piping a pdfkit PDF to Fastify

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, fastify

From what I've read, his should work. But it just downloads an empty document. So I must be handling the pipe incorrectly.

It works fine if I pipe it to `fs.createWriteStream` instead...

```
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'

const downloadPdfRoute = async (app) => {
    app.get('/download/:filename', async (req, reply) => {

        const doc = new PDFDocument()

        reply.type('application/pdf')
        reply.header(
            'content-disposition',
            `attachment; filename="${req.params.filename}"`
        )

        doc.pipe(reply.raw)

        doc.text('Hello, this is your PDF content.')

        doc.end()
    })
}

export default downloadPdfRoute
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: After further investigation by OP, it turned out that the `return` keyword was required for this to work, hence I updated my answer to include that.

---

Fastify also supports sending a [stream](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Reply/#streams) like this:

```
return reply.send(doc);
```

So you should try doing that instead of `doc.pipe(reply.raw);` which is [not recommended](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Reply/#raw) because of the `.raw` usage:

> [...] the use of `Reply.raw` functions is at your own risk as you are skipping all the Fastify logic of handling the HTTP response.

Your original code works for me just fine BTW, so maybe you should try extracting your code in a fresh environment to see if you can reproduce this.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Maybe it is something else in my app that's breaking it then.

Comment: It's one of my plugins. If I disable them all it works. But enabling one at a time to find out which one it is, doesn't tell me anything. So it must be several?! Is there something I am doing wrong with my plugins?

Comment: Are you referring to your browser plugins?

Comment: No, sorry, fastify plugins (mine). I had assumed I'm doing some manipulation in one of them that's breaking it. But commenting them out gives different results every time.

Comment: Ok I've figured it out. Mad, but it's because I was not returning the reply.send. So 'reply.send(doc)' produces an empty document, but 'return reply.send(doc)' works fine. I can't figure out why exactly as there's no code running after it that I'm aware of. But hey! Your reply was helpful so if you want to add the 'return' in, I'll accept it as the answer!

Comment: @user4893295 Sure, I added a disclaimer and edited the answer :)